# How to open localhost in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview, ip, flutterwebviewplugin

**What I m trying:**

Open a local host in flutter WebView. I am using [This](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) plugin and this project is running in Django with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/. I want to open this in my flutter app.

**What I have tried:**

After searching SO answers, URL: http://myIPaddress:8000/.

**UPDATE**

I am providing internet from mobile.

[image: This is my local IP address]

I am using http://192.168.43.55:8080/ is not working and also http://192.168.43.1:8080/

Any suggestion will work, thanks.

Comment: What's not working? `http://127.0.0.1:8000/.` is not going to work as it's localhost in the device where you run the app and not the server localhost. `http://myIPaddress:8000/.` where `myIPaddress` is the ip of the server in the same network as the device, should work unless I miss something.

Comment: `http://myIPaddress:8000/` is not working

Comment: Have you tested `http://myIPaddress:8000/` in desktop and mobile browser? Does it work?

Comment: Are you running / debugging in the Android emulator, the iOS simulator, on on device?  In the Android emulator, you'd have to use a 10.0.2.2 based address - see https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.  For simulator, it should work as you have it.  For device, see comment above from Claudio (there may be other options, but that might be simplest).

Comment: Yes. In desktop and mobile, nothing is working.

Comment: Yes, I have already gone through this. but I m using a physical device.which is my mobile and also from this device I'm providing internet to the desktop.

Comment: What are you using in as `myIPaddress`? if `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` works in the desktop, replacing `127.0.0.1` by a valid local ip should work too.

Comment: I have Updated the Question with `myIPaddress` but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `http://10.0.2.2:8000`. If you get a cleartext error, in your `AndroidManifest.xml` add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` under the application tag

Answer (score 0):

With Android emulator, you can access the localhost by providing the IPv4 with http:// that means http://192.168.43.55:8080/ should be accessible from your flutter webview application.